# Cannot Adjust Joomla Smart Search Module Width

Tags: search, joomla

I am using the Joomla smart search module. I tried to adjust the "Search Field Size" to increase the box size but nothing happened.
https://www.spacebizguide.com/

Then I tried to edit the template, but nothing happened too. I am using the latest Joomla version 3.8.2.

So, where can I change the search box width?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now I need to have some default text appear inside the search box, example: "Search..." How can I update the placeholder text? And also how to make the search box mobile responsive?

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS style from Bootstrap that is affecting the width:

```css
.input-medium {
    width: 150px;
}
```

I would suggest adding this to your custom.css:

```css
form#mod-finder-searchform .input-medium {
    width: 150px;
}
```